# Passing parameters in url (switch from curl to HTTP GET)

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

Currently, I am using curl to make request to the server:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true -v -d '{

      "query": 
      {
        "match_all" : { }
      }
         "fields" : ["my_field"]    
}'
```

How can I change it to browser query like:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty=true&.........
```

that can be opened in Google Chrome, foe example.

How JSON will be transfered into GET parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a chrome app - rest client such as postman and use HTTP POST.

However if you have to use it directly on browser you need to pass the entire json request body as the [source](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html) parameter.

The request body should be [url-encoded](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) .
For the example in the question it would look something like

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?source=%7B+%22query%22%3A+%7B%22match_all%22%3A+%7B%7D%7D%2C%22fields%22+%3A+%5B%22my_field%22%5D+%7D
```

Comment: Nice answer. Fore ease of use, I would recommend the Sense console from Marvel (available at the following URL : http://localhost:9200/_plugin/marvel/sense/index.html).